# How to apply value via URL for custom field when documents are added to document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Firstly I am pretty new to Sharepoint.. I have found grave difficulty finding tutorials on usecases of webparts, how they integrate with eachother, best practices, ect.. so please forgive me.

Anyways, In sharepoint, I have setup a project dashboard showcasing some lists for details of specific project; documents for the project; issues found; and tasks. Each list is displayed on this page as webparts. I am filtering each list on the webpart page utilizing custom field ProjectID via "Query String (URL) Filter".

**Regarding my issue...** When adding new items to those lists, I have used the form webpart (utilizing newform.asp) on same web part page and pre-populating the ProjectID. Since document libraries dont utilize a newform.asp, I am not sure how to have the projectID populate when new documents are added. Is there a known solution for this? Should I be using a document library? I just want the users to attach files(specifications ect..) for a project.. I suppose I could just have custom list and require attachment, but not sure if that would be best practice.